# How can I change the BackgroundColor of current row?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, devexpress, background-color

I'm evaluating DeveloperExpress WPF controls. How can I change the `BackgroundColor` of the current row of DevExpress `GridControl`?

Comment: It's not clear which control your are trying and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Marc, generally  the best place to find the solution for 3'rd party controls is their documentation and forums; here is a code snippet from devexpress forum post -

```
<Window x:Class="DXGrid_ChangeRowAppearance.Window1" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" 
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="505">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SelectedRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRowContent}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" AutoPopulateColumns="True">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView AutoWidth="True" MultiSelectMode="Row" 
                     ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                     AllowGrouping="False" 
                     RowStyle="{StaticResource SelectedRowStyle}">
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2066.aspx

I think the key here is to use `Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow"` in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716606/how-to-change-the-color-of-selected-row-in-devexpressgrid) previous post will help you.

Furthermore I would highly recommend to have a look into the devexpress online documentation [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic).

You can also search the official Forum on the DevExpress website. There are many people facing the same problem.

Hope that helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've seen that post but unfortunately that's not the solution. I've also tried documentation but it's not complete.